Software center vs apt reporting of updates
The Software center reports updates are available:

While apt shows those updates are already installed:
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]      
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:6 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla InRelease                       
Fetched 257 kB in 4s (68.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

~$ apt list firefox
Listing... Done
firefox/mozilla,now 133.0~build2 amd64 [installed]
firefox/mozilla 133.0~build2 i386

~$ apt list snapd
Listing... Done
snapd/jammy-updates,now 2.66.1+22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

Why is there a update discrepancy between Software center and apt?

What happens if you click Update to the packages shown as having updates?

What happens if you apt update and apt upgrade then restart the App Center?

@BeastOfCaerbannog That fixed the problem! It reported "Installing" and took a few minutes to complete (As normal). Software center now reports "Up to Date". Looks like a answer to me.

@user535733 I tried that but it didn't work. I always use apt to update my system instead of App center.

@stumblebee Yes, but that doesn't really answer the question "Why is there a update discrepancy between Software center and apt?" I suppose that it has something to do with caching though, but I don't know.
